# how to set the postion of a draggable object with respect to the droppable object

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop

hi i have a div named bodyArea and i want to drag an ibject into the div..

when i drag the object i want the object gets appended to the div at the exact same position where i am realeasing the dragable object..

but due to some issues(which i cant find its not working properly..

here's my code below

```
 $("#bodyArea").droppable({ 
                drop: function(event, ui){
                    //this is so that the element "sticks" even when tab is changed.
                    ui.draggable.addClass("draggedout");
                                    $(this).append(ui.draggable.css({'top': event.pageY-$(this).offset().top,'left': event.pageX-$(this).offset().left}));// this line is what i added extra.
//and its for this line that draggable object is getting appended but not at the desired position

                },
                //changes current tab to the tab the piece belongs to when dragged out of body area
                out: function(event, ui){
                    ui.draggable.removeClass("draggedout");
                    var whichTab = ui.draggable.parent().attr("id");
                    $("#piecesArea").tabs('select' , whichTab);
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not that familiar with the draggable / droppable jQuery UI functionality, but you should be able to get the element under the drop event using `document.elementFromPoint( x, y )` , and insert your object before or after that element as needed.

```
$this.hide(); // hide it momentarily so the unlerlying element is visible
element = document.elementFromPoint( event.pageX, event.pageY );
$this.insertBefore(element).show();
```